# delimiter problem with TiKZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

This file gives me the following error message

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd} T \arrow[r,"\langle f,g \rangle"] &  G   \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}

! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \delimiter 
l.5 ...,"\langle f,g \rangle"] &  G   \end{tikzcd}
```

If I change `f,g` to simply f then it runs fine.  But I need `f,g` for this arrow.  How can I get that?

Comment: prblem is comma between `f` and `g`. try to envlose them with curly braces: `"\langle {f,g} \rangle"`

Comment: @Zarko Yes.  Can you make that an answer?

Comment: done. see answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

options in `\arrow[...]` are separated by commas. in your case, where you also use comma for separate variables in math expression, you need to encapsulate expression in curly braces. so, instead:

```
"\langle f,g \rangle"
```

you need to write

```
"\langle {f,g} \rangle"
```